# Caching stack databases between builds in Gitlab CI

Tags: haskell, gitlab-ci, haskell-stack

I have a large-ish, multi-language project using CMake to build. In this there is a part written in Haskell, and it uses `stack` to build. The CI builds are handled by Gitlab CI and run in a *docker executor*. During creation of the docker image ghc is downloaded using `stack setup`. The Haskell-part of the build still takes a rather long time though, since it downloads and builds all required packages anew for each build.

To cache the local database I added

```
cache:
  paths:
    - src/utils/.stack-work
```

(The stack YAML file lives in `src/utils/`, and the three Haskell packages live in dirs there too.)

This didn't really speed up the build that much though. After reading more carefully about [stack databases](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#different-databases) I realised that snapshots are put into `STACK_ROOT` (`~/.stack`). Studying the options for stack suggests that there is no way to specify that snapshots should be stored separately from `STACK_ROOT`.

Given that Gitlab CI seems to only allow caching of items in the build dir I think I'm left with two options:

- Use `stack --stack-root <folder under build> ...` to place the `STACK_ROOT` in the build dir and then cache the whole thing. This means my cache goes from less than 100M to about 1.6G!
- Pre-fetch the snapshot we're currently on into the docker image we're using for building.

Now for my questions:

- Am I correct in thinking that snapshots *always* are stored in `STACK_ROOT`?
- Is there a way to pre-fetch a specific snapshot, similar to how `stack setup` fetches ghc?

Or maybe I'm completely wrong, and there's a better route towards limiting the cache size.

Comment: Hmm, what about making the packages required by your project part of the Docker image? We use a similar setup: Gitlab-CI + Docker executor. But we build the project once when *creating* the Docker image. This way stack has a chance to download and build all the dependencies and they are left as part of the docker image. The only downside is that we need to update the image if we switch stack snapshots....

Comment: Yes, that would be one way to do what I call "pre-fetch the snapshot we're currently using" :) I'd just really like something as nice as `stack setup`, that also pulls in the chosen snapshot. I don't switch snapshots that often, so updating the image when I do is not a terrible burden... it would of course be nicer if I could avoid that too :)

Answer (score 1):

After @dsign's comment and a bit of thinking I've come to a solution that is satisfactory:

- Yes, pre-fetching by (sort of) building the software once during docker image build is all right.
- The way to pre-fetch is by running `stack install --only-dependencies`.